# Using joint, marginal, conditional pmf/pdf to compute each other

Tags: probability

Can someone please explain to me how if you are given two of the following three then you are able to compute the third: joint, marginal, conditional pmf/pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Because whatever is *whatever*, the joint probability *whatever* function, the conditional probability *whatever* function, and the marginal probability *whatever* function are related by an identity.

$$\varphi_{\small X,Y}(x,y)=\varphi_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,\varphi_{\small Y}(y) $$

So if you know two functions, you will be able to find the third.